# Notifications through Dylib Injection on MacOSX in c++

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, notifications, dylib

I am attempting to write a .dylib in c++ that will make a notification after injection. It has not had any errors nor output.

in main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include "NotificationHelper.h"
#include <cstdlib>

void displayNotification(const char* message) {
    std::string command = "osascript -e 'display notification \"";
    command += message;
    command += "\" with title \"Notification from dylib\"'";
    system(command.c_str());
}


__attribute__((constructor))
static void beckett() {
    displayNotification("Hello from dylib");
}
```

in NotificationHelper.h:

```
#ifndef NotificationHelper_h
#define NotificationHelper_h

void displayNotification(const char* message);

#endif /* NotificationHelper_h */
```

Note: I am on MacOS and injecting through the  DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES command. Compiling the main.cpp file as a .dylib using g++ and the -dynamiclib and -framework Foundation flags

I am expecting a notification banner in the corner to be titled "Notification from dylib" and say "Hello from dylib." I have tried using snprintf and objective-c to write the notification helper.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by disabling SIP (System Integrity Protection)

Comment: Wow, sledgehammer.  That will disable system updates at minimum.  What process are you trying to inject your dylib into?  System processes are 'protected'.

Comment: Into the Notes app. (this was because it has all notifications enabled and is rather simple.) My computer is already outdated enough that system updates will not work (unless for security 10.15) I had already removed the code signature and it still did not work. Disabling S.I.P was the conclusion I had came to.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm not expecting any further updates to Catalina either.